# How do I import and use my python package?

Tags: python, module, pypi, twine

## problem

I am trying to publish and use a package I created, here is the directory structure

```
my_package_folder
|
|-build
|-dist
|-setup.py
|-my_package_name
||
||-my_package_file.py
||-__init__.py
||
||-request_folder
|||
|||-request_file.py
|||-__init__.py
```

### setup.py

```
VERSION = '1.0.0'
DESCRIPTION = 'api package'
LONG_DESCRIPTION = 'longer package description'

# Setting up
setup(
    name="my_package_settings_name",
    version=VERSION,
    author="John Smith",
    author_email="<email@email.com>",
    url='https://github.com/the-project/project-name',
    description="api client package",
    long_description="api client",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[],

    keywords=['python'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
    ]
)
```

#### my_package_file.py

```
from request_folder.request_file import Request

class Api:
    def __init__(self): #not important implementation details
```

#### request.py

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen


class Request:
    def __init__(self): # unimportant implementation details
```

Then I run the following commands:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

this uploads the package to pypi and succeeds. However, when I try and download and use my package, i am unable to import and use the code the import fails

```
pip install my_package_settings_name==1.0.0
```

#### script.py

```
from  my_package_settings_name import Api
```

the import fails to find the package. I am not the best at python so I think there must be something small I am missing. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try:

`from  my_package_settings import Api`

Answer (score 1):

The problem that is confusing you is that your *package name* is actually different from the *python modules* that it contains.  You've uploaded "my_package_settings_name", which contains the module `my_package_name`.  Thus, assuming that your `Api` class is defined inside of `my_package_name/init.py`, you should use:

```
from my_package_name import Api
```